# How to force Sonar to run Integration tests from Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, integration-testing, sonarqube

I use following things:

- maven - to build project
- jenkins - for CI
- sonar - for code analysis

My project contains unit and integration tests. I have configured above mentioned tools to work together.

Integration tests are separated from unit tests. To run integration test I need to run maven with specific profile.
Sonar executes unit tests and gather metrics.

How can I force Sonar to execute specific profile and gather result from integration tests?

**EDIT**

My surefire and failsafe sections:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*IT*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>${skip.integration.tests}</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**EDIT 2**

When I run jenkins build with `clean packag -DskipTests` because otherwise my tests will be executed twice. 
First time during jenkins build and second time when sonar executes them. The problem is that when I start jenkins build with `clean verify` goal. I can see that both unit and integration tests are executed. And after this step Sonar starts his job and **only** unit tests are executed.

**EDIT 3**

I have managed to work sonar with maven from console. I've added following profile and proper plugin to my `pom.xml`:

```
<profile>
            <id>sonar</id>
            <!-- Enable coverage computation via JaCoCo for Sonar's needs -->
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!--
                        Compute integration test coverage for Sonar
                        Note: REQUIRES MAVEN 3 - throws InstantiationException: java.util.List otherwise
                        Beware: Sonar doesn't run the verify phase; you should always 'mvn clean install' before running sonar
                    -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName> <!-- default: argLine -->
                            <includes>
                                <include>pl/cyfronet/**</include>
                            </includes>
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-integration.exec</destFile> <!-- agent -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-integration.exec</dataFile> <!-- report -->
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>agent</id>
                                <goals><goal>prepare-agent</goal></goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <!--
                                Generate coverage report html in target/site/jacoco/ from target/jacoco.exec
                                Exec.: mvn verify site
                                -->
                                <id>report</id>
                                <phase>site</phase>
                                <goals><goal>report</goal></goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
</profile>
```

I've also added `settings.xml` file to my `~/.m2/` directory.

```
<settings>
 <profiles>
   <profile>
     <id>sonar</id>
     <activation>
       <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
     </activation>
     <properties>
       <!-- Example for MySQL-->
       <sonar.jdbc.url>
       jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
       </sonar.jdbc.url>
       <sonar.jdbc.username>sonar</sonar.jdbc.username>
       <sonar.jdbc.password>sonar</sonar.jdbc.password>
     </properties>
   </profile>
 </profiles>
</settings>
```

After that I run mvn with following parameters:
`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/jacoco-integration.exec`. Reports were correctly generated to sonar.

I was trying to use it in my jenkins. I have replaced post-build sonar with maven goal `sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/jacoco-integration.exec` but it doesn't work. My integration tests are not invoked. Any ideas?

Comment: If you have to use a profile to run integration tests than you are going the wrong way, cause maven has explicit life-cycle parts (pre-integration-test, integration-test and post-integration-tests) which can be used in combination with maven-failsafe-plugin to run integration tests (`mvn clean verify`). Furthermore SonarQube does not run unit tests. Maven runs the tests and either via jenkins plugin or via maven plugin the metrics will be transfered to the SonarQube server.

Comment: I have changed my pom.xml so now. When I call `mvn clean verify` all my tests are executed. But despite of that builds called by jenkins are executed without integration tests.

Comment: How have you named your integration tests? According to the naming conventions of [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#includes).

Comment: I use `IT*.java` name convention. I have added snippet of my `pom.xml` file.

Comment: The exclude in maven-surefire-plugin is not necessary, cause it's default. In your Jenkins configuration how do you call Maven there?

Comment: I am using `free-style software project`. My goal to build is `clean package -DskipTests`. I am skiping tests because sonar is executing tests once again.

Comment: You have to execute the "verify" goal from Jenkins. "clean package" will never execute the integration tests (with default config).

Comment: I am not sure if you're correct. When I build project from jenkins perspective I my unit tests are executed twice. At first when `clean package` is called, and later when sonar needs to generate report.

Comment: Did you try it (with verify)? Btw I would recommend to update your SonarQube because in current versions, tests are no longer executed twice and the reports from the "main" build are reused. hth

Comment: Yes. I tried to with `verify`. Post Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to do this by calling manual maven scripts from jenkins. So everything is working without Sonar plugin for jenkins. It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Can you share the relevant "maven scripts" for reference?